# Учебник по синтаксиску и пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Я очень плохо знаю синтаксис и пунктуацию. Недавно вообще считал, что в грамматической основе обязательно должно присутствовать и подлежащие, и сказуемое (!). Однако я не против все узнать и попытаться, собственно говоря, выучить.

Требования к учебнику: упражнения (все-таки много нового там для меня, поэтому они очень важны) и объяснение доступным языком (для начинающих).

К примеру, я не знаю виды односоставных предложений (точнее, я знаю названия, но не дифференцирую их), плохо делаю синтаксический разбор - по крайней мере, я так считаю.

Можете ли Вы предложить какой-нибудь учебник, в котором сначала описывается синтаксис, а затем уже рассматриваются случаи постановки знаков препинания? Готов скачать его в электронном формате - если, конечно, будет.

Спасибо за прочтение и внимание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уважаемый! Знаете, это довольно совестно не знать всего этого. Но! Очень похвально и хорошо, что Вы рано или поздно замечаете в своих знаниях пробелы и пытаетесь их восполнить. Учиться, как говорится, никогда не поздно! Дерзайте! ;-)
А что касается учебников.. 
Я бы Вам с огромной радостью посоветовала один прекрасный учебник. Издательством он 1974 года "Просвещение". Авторы: В.Ф.Греков, С.Е.Крючков, Л.А.Чешко "Пособие для занятий по русскому языку". Вообще все учебники, книги советских времен очень содержательны, поучительны. Книги, благодаря которыМ детей действительно можно чему-то научить! Я не знаю, найдете ли ВЫ такую книгу или нет. Но если бы нашли, то было совсем хорошо. Удачи Вам!!!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скачать учебник: И. Голуб "Русский язык. Все темы для подготовки к ЕГЭ".

http://za-partoj.ru/d/rusl/rusl288.htm

Comment: Учебник скачать удалось. Однако не очень понравился: cлишком-слишком кратко :)

Comment: А почему Вам тогда не воспользоваться обычными школьными учебниками для 8 и 9 классов: Бархударов, Крючков, Максимов, Чешко "Русский язык.

Comment: Кстати, то, что я не знаю всё это, вполне оправдано: я только в этом году пойду в восьмой класс. :)

Comment: http://yandex.ru/images/search?source=wiz&img_url=http%3A%2F%2Fcontent.foto.mail.ru%2Fmail%2Fmakhrakova5%2F_answers%2Fi-1245.jpg&uinfo=sw-1920-sh-1080-ww-1071-wh-643-pd-1-wp-16x9_1920x1080&text=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&noreask=1&pos=1&lr=172&rpt=simage&pin=1 

Может, нужно выучить это? :)

Comment: UPD: ознакомился с односоставными предложениями. 

Когда его убили, то мы уже были дома. В данном случае придаточная часть относится к односоставному неопределенно-личному предложению, да? Глагол во множественном числе и в прошедшем времени ведь. Я прав насчет этого? :)

Comment: Да, это неопределенно-личное предложение, что видно по смыслу (производителем действия является неопр. лицо) и по форме (мн. числ прош. времени). Но СПП составлено неверно, правильно будет: Когда его убили, нас не было дома. Союз КОГДА со значением одновременности событий. А союз КОГДА...ТО близок по значению к союзу ЕСЛИ...ТО, например:Когда говорят, то надо слушать.